# How do I fix my code, so it reverses the elements in my list?

Tags: python

I'm trying to create my own reverse function. Here is my code:

```
X = [1,2,3,4,5]

def reverZe(Lis):
    nlst = []
    for i in range (1,len(Lis)+1):
        nlst.append(Lis[-1])
    return nlst

new = reverZe(X)

print(new)
```

The results should reverse the list 'X' into a list that is `[5,4,3,2,1]`

The problem is that the output keeps coming back out to only the last element *5* that is `[5,5,5,5,5]`. How do I fix this?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to change my call function to new = reverZe. However, that does still not change the problem of the porgram.

Comment: `nlst.append(Lis[-i])` ?

Answer (score 2):

nlst = Lis[::-1], this is a concept of slicing a list in python.

```
X = [1,2,3,4,5]

def reverZe(Lis):
  nlst = Lis[::-1]
  return nlst

new = reverZe(X)

print(new)
```

The output of the above program will be [5,4,3,2,1]

Answer (score 0):

You have used `Lis[-1]` which always accesses the last element in the list and thus only returns that.

Use this instead `Lis[-i]`

```
def reverseInPlace(Lis):
    nlst = []
    for i in range (1,len(Lis)+1):
        nlst.append(Lis[-i])
    return nlst
```

That should work.

Answer (score 0):

Just use simple pythonic list slicing:

```
In [1]: l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

In [2]: l[::-1]
Out[2]: [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

Explanation: slicing has three parameter: `start:stop:step`. So, here starting from 0, it will go till the end but with -1 increment. As a result, it will do a reverse looping from start to end.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some processes you can follow:

```
X = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

# corrected version of your code
def reverZe(Lis):
    nlst = []
    for i in range(1, len(Lis)+1):
        nlst.append(Lis[-i])
    return nlst

#Some other processes you can follow:

# def reverZe(Lis):
#     nlst = []
#     for i in Lis[::-1]:
#         nlst.append(i)
#     return nlst

# def reverZe(Lis):
#     nlst = list(reversed(Lis))
#     return nlst

# def reverZe(Lis):
#   nlst = Lis[::-1]
#   return nlst


new = reverZe(X)

print(new)
```